# dropzonejs not success event

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I have a problem with my Dropzone. It does not trigger the success while the file and download. Here is an extract of my code ([code on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tycoons/mv908ws4/5/)):

```
this.on("success", function(file,response) {
    alert("fichier télécharger avec succes");
    console.log(file,response);
    var content=tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    setTimeout(function(){ $('div.dz-success').remove(); }, 500);
});
```

The addition works perfectly but the progress bar remains blocked at 100% without declining the success story.

[image error and success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjZ22.png)

Comment: IMHO most likely your jquery selector does not match the div, but there is no way to tell, check the [mcve] page.

Comment: I put a complete example it only misses the file upload.php

Comment: So much code in your jsFiddle, nobody is going to read through all of that.  Try to create a [*minimal*, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to look at.

Comment: to be simple if I check the field of my server-side form with php
I return the error messages in text / plain but I do not have access to the success function of dropzone while the file is to download the progressbar remains at 100% and no longer suprime the file at the end of the download as usual the success function